# What C# compiles when using namespaces

Tags: c#, compilation, namespaces

We have two applications that each compile their own code with some of the code being shared (mainly data related). It felt natural to split this design up into three namespaces and try to enforce that namespace `Foo` never imports namespace `Bar` but either can import namespace `Shared`.

I hope Venn diagrams are appreciated as a visualization:
[image]

However one of the classes between `Foo` and `Bar` slipped through the cracks and someone referenced a class from `Bar` inside `Foo` despite the enforcement.

And that got me wondering if how the C# compiler actually deals with this? The way I see it, one of two things could happen.

1. The entire namespace gets compiled into `Foo`. Leaving the diagram to look like this:
   [image]
2. Or the compiler is smart enough just to extract the necesarry class. Making the diagram look like this:
   [image]

I can't seem to find any documentation on how usings and namespaces compile. It seems like namespaces are just to organise code for developers, not compilers. Yet they provide scope... So I guess #2 applies then? How to even test this?

Comment: You compile code into assemblies, not namespaces. These assemblies themselves are not going to change if they contain references to other assemblies. It's a reference, not a copy of the referenced code.

Comment: How did you try to enforce this?

Comment: Enforced on a interpersonal level, not technological level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no correspondence between namespaces and assemblies: one assembly may contain many namespaces, and one namespace may span many assemblies.

The compiled IL code in an assembly refers to types by their fully qualified names: `Foo.SomeClass` instead of `SomeClass`, `Bar.OtherClass` instead of `OtherClass`, and so on. The compiler's job is to figure out *which* fully qualified type name you really mean when you write the shortened form `SomeClass` -- because you could have defined a class called `SomeClass` in the namespaces `Foo`, `Bar`, or even `System`!

When you write:

```cs
namespace Foo
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
    }
}
```

You are defining a type with a fully qualified name `Foo.SomeClass`.

When you write:

```cs
using Foo;
...
SomeClass instance = new SomeClass();
```

The compiler treats this the same as:

```cs
Foo.SomeClass instance = new Foo.SomeClass();
```

Namespaces are just a construct of convenience for organizing these fully qualified names. When you say `using Foo;`, you are just telling the compiler to search for fully qualified names that start with `Foo.` whenever you type `SomeClass`. There is nothing being "imported" when you write `using Foo;`, it just provides a convenient alternative to writing `Foo.SomeClass` everywhere; nor does any "code" (in the sense of IL instructions being emitted) get generated by your `using`s or your `namespace`s. All it does is tell the compiler to put `Foo.SomeClass` into the IL whenever you write `SomeClass`.

The above is a simplification of a more nuanced set of rules defined in the spec for resolving short-form type names; you can read this for more details: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#namespace-and-type-names) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/namespaces)

The level at which you'd want to enforce the dependencies in your diagrams would be at the assembly reference level: if the Foo project never references the Bar assembly or vice versa, the code would not even compile if you tried to reference a type in one assembly from the other. The namespaces don't really have much to do with that at all, because again, nothing stops you from defining types in the `Foo` namespace but in the `Bar` assembly.

Comment: Ye this makes a lot of sense. It was probably worth mentioning that for one of the applications, we are using Unity3D. So the compilation is kindof outside of our control. Which is probably exactly why I had concerns at first...